# Issues with forking process and pipes in C program

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

C beginner here. My C program is supposed to read a file input.txt line by line and then write a line to one of the mapper_pipes. There are four lines of text and each line gets sent to a different mapper pipe. 4 processes are forked, one for each of the lines of text. The program is properly reading the lines of text from the file, I know because I console log them in the `send_line_to_mapper` function. The code inside the mapper forks which seem to be working since `printf("hello from mapper/n");` prints but it does not print the messages sent through the pipe here `printf("forked mapper read line: %s\n", ibuf);`. Appreciate any help.

### Update 2

*Edit: I moved close to immediatly after fork and now its working.
Closed write end of the pipe after writing to pipe and after forking process that reads from pipe, still not reading EOF.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ALPHA_OFFSET 97
#define LETTERS 26

const int NUM_OF_MAPPERS = 4;
const int NUM_OF_REDUCERS = 26;

const int PIPE_READ_END = 0;
const int PIPE_WRITE_END = 1;
const int PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

int mapper_pipes[4][2];
int reducer_pipes[26][2];

void pipe_wrapper(int pipefd[]) {
    int ret = pipe(pipefd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("Error. Failed when trying to create pipes.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void create_mapper_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(mapper_pipes[i]);
    }
}

void create_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(reducer_pipes[i]);
    }
}

// Prints an error msg and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val, const char* syscall_name) {
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror(syscall_name);
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        //No syscall error we can return
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

void fork_mappers(void) {


    /* Constants useful to all children */
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pid_t mapper_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (mapper_pid == 0) {
            close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
            rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            while(rlen > 0) {    
                printf("read line from forked_mappers, p%d: %s\n", i, ibuf);
                rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            }
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void fork_reducers(void) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pid_t reducer_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (reducer_pid == 0) {

        }
    }
}

void send_lines_to_mappers(void) {
    int wlen = 0;
    char obuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int ob_size;
    int count = 0;

    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]; // a buffer for each line of the file
    FILE *input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // read the input file line by line
    while(fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) > 0) {
        printf("read line from send_lin_to_mappers: %s\n", buff);
        ob_size = sizeof buff;
        switch(count) {
            case 0 :
                write(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            case 1 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            case 2 :
                write(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            case 3 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                break;
            default :
                printf("you did something wrong in send_lines_to_mappers loop");
        }
        count++;
    }
    fclose(input_file);
}

int main(void) {
    // Setup the mapper pipes
    create_mapper_pipes();
    create_reducer_pipes();
    fork_mappers();
    //fork_reducers();
    send_lines_to_mappers();

    return 0;
}
```

### Updated Code After Help From Comments

Now everything seems to be working but forked processes in `fork_mappers` never leave while loop and exit.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ALPHA_OFFSET 97
#define LETTERS 26

const int NUM_OF_MAPPERS = 4;
const int NUM_OF_REDUCERS = 26;

const int PIPE_READ_END = 0;
const int PIPE_WRITE_END = 1;
const int PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

int mapper_pipes[4][2];
int reducer_pipes[26][2];

void pipe_wrapper(int pipefd[]) {
    int ret = pipe(pipefd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("Error. Failed when trying to create pipes.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void create_mapper_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(mapper_pipes[i]);
    }
}

void create_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(reducer_pipes[i]);
    }
}

// Prints an error msg and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val, const char* syscall_name) {
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror(syscall_name);
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        //No syscall error we can return
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

void fork_mappers(void) {


    /* Constants useful to all children */
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pid_t mapper_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (mapper_pid == 0) {
            rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            while(rlen > 0) {    
                printf("read line from forked_mappers, p%d: %s\n", i, ibuf);
                rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            }
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void fork_reducers(void) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pid_t reducer_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (reducer_pid == 0) {

        }
    }
}

void send_lines_to_mappers(void) {
    int wlen = 0;
    char obuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int ob_size;
    int count = 0;

    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]; // a buffer for each line of the file
    FILE *input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // read the input file line by line
    while(fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) > 0) {
        printf("read line from send_lin_to_mappers: %s\n", buff);
        ob_size = sizeof buff;
        switch(count) {
            case 0 :
                write(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                break;
            case 1 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                break;
            case 2 :
                write(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                break;
            case 3 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                break;
            default :
                printf("you did something wrong in send_lines_to_mappers loop");
        }
        count++;
    }
    fclose(input_file);
}

int main(void) {
    // Setup the mapper pipes
    create_mapper_pipes();
    create_reducer_pipes();
    fork_mappers();
    //fork_reducers();
    send_lines_to_mappers();

    return 0;
}
```

### C Code

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ALPHA_OFFSET 97
#define LETTERS 26

const int NUM_OF_MAPPERS = 4;
const int NUM_OF_REDUCERS = 26;

const int PIPE_READ_END = 0;
const int PIPE_WRITE_END = 1;
const int PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE = 32;

int mapper_pipes[4][2];
int reducer_pipes[26][2];

void pipe_wrapper(int pipefd[]) {
    int ret = pipe(pipefd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("Error. Failed when trying to create pipes.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void create_mapper_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(mapper_pipes[i]);
    }
}

void create_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(reducer_pipes[i]);
    }
}

// Prints an error msg and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val, const char* syscall_name) {
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror(syscall_name);
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        //No syscall error we can return
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

void fork_mappers(void) {


    /* Constants useful to all children */
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pid_t mapper_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        printf("%d\n", mapper_pid);
        if (mapper_pid == 0) {
            printf("hello from mapper/n");
            rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            while(rlen > 0) {    
                printf("forked mapper read line: %s\n", ibuf);
                rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            }
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void fork_reducers(void) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pid_t reducer_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (reducer_pid == 0) {

        }
    }
}

void send_lines_to_mappers(void) {
    int wlen = 0;
    char obuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int obptr = 0;
    int count = 0;

    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]; // a buffer for each line of the file
    FILE *input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // read the input file line by line
    while(fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) > 0) {
        printf("read line: %s\n", buff);
        switch(count) {
            case 0 :
                write(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END], obuf, obptr);
                break;
            case 1 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END], obuf, obptr);
                break;
            case 2 :
                write(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END], obuf, obptr);
                break;
            case 3 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END], obuf, obptr);
                break;
            default :
                printf("you did something wrong in send_lines_to_mappers loop");
        }
        count++;
    }
    fclose(input_file);
}

int main(void) {
    // Setup the mapper pipes
    create_mapper_pipes();
    create_reducer_pipes();
    fork_mappers();
    //fork_reducers();
    send_lines_to_mappers();

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
9592
9593
9594
9595
read line: I like coding in C.

read line: I like manually allocating memory, and opening the registers window in Visual Studio to see the values of the eax register and blitting graphics to the screen and all the stuff that Dr. Dobbs wrote about in the 90s.

read line: My programming friends seem to believe that understanding this level of programming is good in a hand-wavy, theoretical sense, but when you consider all the web development, Java frameworks, and existing libraries most programmers today rely on, it's hard to really pin down a solid answer to the question "Why learn C?"

read line: This is my attempt to answer that question, and I believe it comes down to the basic programming concept of abstraction.

0
0
0
0
```

Comment: `printf("hello from mapper/n");`. You have the newline character wrong. Change that to `\n`. To ensure it's flushed to stdout and eliminate buffering issues that might be confusing things.

Comment: nice catch, its printing hello from mapper now but still does not reach `printf("forked mapper read line: %s\n", ibuf);` any ideas?

Comment: In `send_lines_to_mappers` why do you `fgets` into `buff` but then write the contents of `obuf` into the pipe? Furthermore, `obptr` is always 0 and hence `write` is being told the buffer size is 0 anyway. Seems like some fundamental issues there.

Comment: C does not have constants. `const int NUM_OF_MAPPERS = 4` are variables with external linkage, so they occupy memory and might not be optimised as one might expect from C++. As you already have some macros for arrays (which cannot be `const int ...` for exactly the reason I stated), you should follow one style and stick with `#define`s. There is nothing wrong with them - C is not C++. Consistency is sometimes more important than fancy features.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for letting me know, I've been struggling with understanding the correct usage of `const` and `#define`

Comment: @kaylum That makes sense, I was following some example code and forgot to change some things. I update the write methods but its still not working. Would you mind taking a look at this updated code? http://pastebin.com/NNNaPweF

Comment: Please do not post links to external code. Either ask a new question or update this question with the new code (preferably as an addition rather than a replacement to preserve history). External links can go away and render this question useless for future readers. `read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000)`. Why are you reading 1000 bytes when `ibuf` is only 32 bytes. That results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @kaylum I'll make sure not to do that again. I added updated code. I increased ibuf to 1000 bytes because 32 bytes was too short. Now forked_mappers processes are reading from the pipe correctly but they don't leave there while loop and thus never exit which keeps the program running. Would you mind taking another look?

Comment: After `fork` both the parent and child processes have a copy of the pipe. In both processes, after `fork`, you need to immediately close the end of the pipe that the respective process does not need to use. To see why, you need to note that, for example, the child process' `read` call will never see EOF until the write end of the pipe is fully closed. But since the child itself has the write end of the pipe opened that will never happen and hence the `read` call will block indefinetely even if  the parent process has closed the write end of the pipe (which you actually havent done either).

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the help mate :) I'd be sure to accept an answer if you post one.